# How to use Hybrid Graphic Switch on Sony Vaio Z?

Tags: 11.04, graphics, sony, vaio

I got it to install nicely and it's all working, but I don't know which graphics card is being used nor how to switch between. I tried installing the official Nvidia drivers, but then I could not boot up my computer afterwards so I have not installed them again after doing a reinstall of Ubuntu.

PS, if you have a grub install failure during install, the key is to tell it where to install the bootloader at the very beginning of the installation, on your partition selection screen (choose dev/mapper, not the /dev/sda it defaults to).

Answer (score 3):

Might want to check this question out:  [Problems with graphics of Sony Vaio Z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8247/problems-with-graphics-of-sony-vaio-z)

The quick answer is that you *can* get both graphics cards to work, but you will have to reboot to switch between them.  Also, from the little googling I did, it looks like a royal pain to set up right now. (see link) Probably in a year the process will be nice and smooth, but right now its pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use bumblebee. Have a look at this websites:
https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux
http://linux-hybrid-graphics.blogspot.com/